# Filtrar coluna por condicional

Tags: python, pandas, filter

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, aqui eu quero obter um dataset que contenha todos os países, EXCETO o país 'United Kingdon'

Usei:
df1.loc[df1('Country')!='United Kingdom']

Mas obtenho:
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

O que estou fazendo de errado?
Como eu faria o filtro de forma correta?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: `df1('Country')` é interpretado como uma chamada de função em Python. Porém df1 é um dataframe, e não uma função, por isso o erro. Provavelmente você quis retornar os valores de uma coluna, o que é feito por colchetes no pandas (`df1["Country]`)

Answer (score 0):

O problema realmente é o uso dos parênteses - df1('Country'). O correto é usar df1['Country'].

Alternativamente, vc consegue fazer o mesmo slice sem precisar usar loc:

```
df1 = df1[df1['Country']!='United Kingdom']
```

Output:

```
df1
        Country  UserId
14      Germany      95
13       France      88
31        Spain      31
3       Belgium      25
33  Switzerland      22
27     Portugal      20
19        Italy      15
```